# Является ли тип встроенным?

Tags: c++

Каким образом определить, является тип встроенным или пользовательским?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Положим, надо это определить для типа `x_t`.

**Способ любителя.** Создать маленькую программку без инклюдов и вписать такой код:

```
x_t a;
```

Если скомпилируется, то тип встроенный.

**Способ профессионала.** Посмотреть справку.

***Добавка.*** В коде можно использовать метафункцию [boost::type_ traits::is_pod](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pod.html)

Comment: .

     ++Способ профессионала

Comment: @mikillskegg, по-моему "Способ любителя" будет побыстрее, если компилятор открыт, конечно же =)

Comment: А как компилятор может быть открыт? Может быть открыт редактор или интегрированная среда разработки (IDE)

Answer (score 11):

- [`Working Draft`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) стандарта C++11 определяет понятие `built-in type` как эквивалентное понятию `fundamental type`.

> В связи с этим, наиболее корректный способ - использовать соответствующую `type trait` из `boost` под названием [`boost::is_fundamental<T>`.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_fundamental.html)

Answer (score 0):

Попробовать унаследоваться.

Comment: В с++11 класс может быть определен как final. Да и в С++2003 некоторые хакерские приемы позволяли достигнуть того же эффекта.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не полный, нужно определить является ли тип плоским (т.н. POD) типом или является ли тип частью языка С++ (например std::string) ?

можно через RTTI

```
#include <typeinfo>

#define IS_BUILTIN(x) (((std::string(typeid(x).name()).find(" ") != std::string::npos && \
                   std::string(typeid(x).name()).find("std::") != std::string::npos) || \
                   std::string(typeid(x).name()).find(" ") == std::string::npos) ? "true" : "false")
```

//дабы не загромождать, удалил main()

Хорошо, с тем, что код выше неудачный, я согласен.
По скольку первый ответ отмечен как правильный, значит речь идет все таки о POD типах.
Вот через шаблоны, определяет является ли тип POD в compile-time

```
template <typename T>
void isNotPOD(T _n)
{
    int n = static_cast<int>(_n);
}

template <typename T>
void isPOD(T n)
{
    isNotPOD(n);
}
```

все по Александреску :) В чем плюс такого подхода? В том, что при вызове isPOD(bar) на этапе компиляции можно получить вменяемое сообщение, типа:

> error: "void isNotPOD<T>(T)"
>           with
>           [
>               T=Bar
>           ]

Почему нельзя просто привести к int? Потому что пользовательский тип может иметь метод 
operator int(){}, но т.к. это run-time код, при компиляции так же будет ошибка.

Comment: - Внезапно макрос и `typeid`, хотя эта же задача решается элементарно  на этапе компиляции с помощью специализации шаблонов.
- Для типа `mynamespace::std::Whatever` ваш код вернет `true`.
- `std::type_info::name()` не стандартизирован и для `std::vector` может вернуть вам, например, `St6vectorIiSaIiEE`.

Comment: 1. А что смущает в макросах и typeid? Макросы активно используются в С++. 
Делать специализацию на каждый тип? 

2. Согласен, тоже об этом подмал, уже после того, как код выложил.

3. Нет, вывод зависит от компилятора, а не от поданного в name() типа. Подобный вывод обычно наблюдается на gcc, мой код расчитан под студийный компилятор (о чем я забыл упомянуть), и там вывод будет  "std::vector<blah blah blah..."

Comment: @Kastaneda, для обобщенного программирования в С++ есть замечательный инструмент - шаблоны. Если Вы с ним еще не знакомы, настоятельно рекомендую познакомиться.

Comment: @Kastaneda

- Вызов `typeid` может занимать на порядок *(например, в 100 раз)* больше времени, чем даже банальный вызов виртуальной функции. Безумная пессимизация на ровном месте не может быть оправдана даже с учетом аргументов про `premature optimization`.

- Некоторые `real-world` проекты вполне себе не используют `RTTI`, так что ваш код на них приведет к `undefined behavior`.

- За макросы в `C++`, кроме случаев типа `BOOST_PREPROCESSOR` бьют по пальцам.

- Никому не нужен код, заточенный исключительно под `cl`, когда можно  простым путем сделать его кросс-платформенным.

Comment: @Kastaneda

- И да, если, скажем, в 12 версии компилятора `cl` добавят `name mangling`, то ваш код завалится из-за проблем, описанных на примере `St6vectorIiSaIiEE`, что, естественно, сложно назвать разумным поведением.

Comment: Про шаблоны я уже написал, специализировать шаблон на каждый встроеный тип - нет уж.

Каждый случай UB описан в стандарте, что-то я не видел там ни чего, связанного с RTTI.

Макросы используются в С++ активно, не для того, чтобы заменить функции (за такие макросы бьют по рукам), а для сокращения код, как в моем случае (за такие не бьют).

name mangling существует со времен первого компилятора С++, и он не влияет на typeid().name().

Про кроссплатформенность да, согласен.

Comment: Кажется я понял вашу идею про шаблоны - не специализировать под каждый тип, а просто заменить макрос шаблоном. Так вы же понимаете, что в таком случае компилятор наплодит столько фукнций, сколько она будет вызвана в коде с разными типами. Код может разбухнуть до неприлично большого размера, хотя конечно это более ближе к C++ way, нежели макросы.